# Is this sentence lignuistically correct?

Tags: grammar, syntax

This is a definition from stockedge.com about Business Houses.

Business Houses are a public or private structure business that forms a group of various companies dealing in different segments

Is the definition from stockedge.com linguistically correct? Shouldn't it either be: "Business House **is** a public or private structure business" or "Business Houses **are** a public or private structure businesses"?

Comment: There is everything wrong with the definition. Unless Business Houses is a name, **Houses** should be lower case. Singulars and Plurals run amok. To call a business a business makes no sense. And the definition tells us very little. In short, it's a mess.

Answer (score -1):

You're correct; it changes from plural form to singular.

It's almost exactly as you state:

> "**a** Business House is a public or private structure business" or "Business Houses are <strike>**a**</strike> public or private structure businesses"?

I added "a" at the start to indicate a singular, and removed it from the second statement because this is the plural form.